# Regular expression, add a line after every x line?

Tags: regex

I tried this in Notepad++ and it works, but when I try to use it in PowerGrep it does not work.

```
(.*\r?\n){9}\K
```

Example is from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/680416/how-to-add-something-every-x-line). 
I want to go to every x line and add new line, using Regular expression in Powergrep if it is possible, because Notepad++ cant do this to multiple files at once.
I tried to find help in https://www.regular-expressions.info/ but I cant find a command to jump to specific line, for example, every 9th line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\K` operator is not widely supported, but  you may work around it using a capturing group like

```
((?:.*\r?\n){9})
```

and replace with `$1Your new line\n`.

You may also use a `$0` backreference to refer to the whole match. Then, use `(?:.*\r?\n){9}` and replace with `$0Your new line\n`.